# Convert pytesseract string output to pandas df

Tags: pandas, python-imaging-library, stringio, pytesser

I have been given receipts from Subway detailing sales, workers, etc throughout the day and need to extract the data for a management class.

I took pictures of  the receipts and processed them with pytesseract into a string separated by \n but now don't know how to use pd.read_csv and StringIO to transform it into a dataframe. Don't if this is the best way to go about it. Also may need to edit the image using cv2 so that it processes better.

```
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\\attachments\\'

monday = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path+'file1-1.jpeg'),lang='eng')

from StringIO import StringIO
mon = pd.read_csv(StringIO(monday),sep=r'\s',lineterminator=r'\n')
print(mon)
```

This is some of the variable monday currently.

```
"\nTIME HOURS :\nPERIOD SALES UNITS WORKED PROD SPLH\nZhan emmoo «Ct (iti ;:t‘«é‘«‘i CSD\n3A-4A $0.00 0 0 0 $0.00\n44-54 =: $0.00 SssOO 0 0 $0.00\n5A-6A $0.00 0 0 0 $0.00\nbA-7A $0.00 0 0 0 $0.00\n7A-BA =s«$0.00-Sss«OOs«*O0.80 0 $0.00\nBA-9A 60,00 . Qge2.00 0 $0.00\nQA-10A $33.68 6 2,00 3.00 $16.84\n104-114 $61.07 9 2.13 4.23 $28.67\n11A-12P$238.82 33 5,00 6.60 $47.76"
```

It should look like this as a dataframe:

```
Period Sales Units Worked Prod SPLH
3A-4A  $0.00  0      0     0   $0.00
bA-7A  $0.00  0      0     0   $0.00
```

Comment: "I have been given receipts from Subway" <— Please don't get this wrong, but couldn't you just ask them for a .xls or .csv file then, instead of something printed?

Comment: I wanted to ask for that but didn't haha. They pulled it directly from the cash register and I doubt the UI there would have a send to csv and then email function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may get the results from tesseract directly into a Pandas dataframe:

```py
monday = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(path+'file1-1.jpeg'),lang='eng', output_type='data.frame')
```

Now `monday` is a dataframe which, however, needs more processing from you, as it contains at least a row for each level in the hierarchy. Check the output and see how you wish to organize it.